# How to change IP Address of Docker container for Edge Module development

Tags: docker, azure-iot-edge

I am developing Azure IoT Edge modules using Visual Studio 2019, on Win 10.  To actually build the modules, a docker container is created for each build of each module.  I'm trying to change the IP address of the container created, because it currently defaults to a 172.x address that is in the public range.  I need it to be a private IP, so our Symantec AV software won't think requests coming from it are external.  The `dotnet restore` is failing because SEP is blocking access to the web to get the index file.

I have tried the following:

1. Set "bip" in my global daemon.json file, like this:

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": false,
  "dns": ["8.8.8.8"],
  "bip": "192.168.1.5/24"
}
```

This doesn't work because after adding that last "bip" line, Docker Desktop restart fails, and further starts fail, with a timeout when starting up the back end.  The error logs for this are not helpful.

2. Edit the module.json file in the solution, like so:

```
      "buildOptions": [ "--build-arg bip=192.168.1.5/24" ],
```

This seems to have absolutely no effect.  The IP address in the container remains in the 172.x space.

Any idea how I can customize the IP address for my docker build containers?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Instead of using a default docker bridge network. Have you tried using a custom [docker network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/) and assigning the network CIDR of your interest?. To add 172.x belongs to private address namespace as per [RFC1918](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  That would require passing in some build options when building the container, and from what I've seen (Item 2 in my question), the build options are being ignored.  I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the second method in my question started working, after a few reboots.  I'm not sure why it didn't work at first, but for now all is working.